# how to loop in asynchronic function

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am new in js and don't understand why my loop is not working.

```js
(async () => {
  let arr = []

  while(ticket.stop != true) {
    let data = await fetch("https://front-test.beta.aviasales.ru/search")
    let commit =  await data.json() 
    let ticketsURL = "https://front-test.beta.aviasales.ru/tickets?" + Object.keys(commit) + "=" + Object.values(commit)
    let ticketFetch = await fetch(ticketsURL)
    let ticket = await ticketFetch.json()
    console.log(ticket)
    arr.push(ticket)
  }
})()
```

Comment: Please kindly tell what do you want to achieve by that code, explain what went wrong based on that code.

Comment: @BatyrkhanAkzholov when I make the fetch req in the final ticketFetch call I am getting an array containing more than 346 items? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

Edit: your code is returning an array containing more than 346 items and what you're trying to do simply looping over and over again and calling them. Can you explain what you're trying to do with your code?

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do with your code but that should vary with your own use case however what you're trying to do is can be summarized in a `async-call-inside-a-loop`. Now one thing to remember is when you create a loop there are two main things to keep in mind,

- loop variables and index
- scope of the loop

The key take is that when you fire a function inside of a loop it gains its own context and therefore persists the value. However directly calling some asynchronous calls will fail. Therefore JavaScript offers you something that can resolve this and they are called `Immediately Invoked Function Expression` or `IIFE` in short. Which is exactly what you have done however you have wrapped the entire loop inside of it.

In a nutshell the IIFE gains its own context so every next IIFE that is created by the loop will work and resolve separately.

```js
const length = array.length;

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    (function(index) {
        const response = // some async call
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: "*[IIFE] is exactly what you have done however you have wrapped the entire loop inside of it.*" - and that was correct. Putting the IIFE inside the loop broke the code, since now you're not even changing the loop variable while the loop runs, making it an infinite loop. (And you didn't fix the actual problem of `ticket.stop` throwing an exception when `ticket` is `undefined`).

Comment: "*directly calling some asynchronous calls will fail*" - no, absolutely not. Using `await` inside loops is fine and exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: @Bergi unfortunately you didn't get the general idea that I am trying to give here. First that I seriously don't know what the OP is trying to do with his code. However I am trying to generalize with a better method to gain a separate stack for the operation.

Comment: A better method? What you're doing is utterly complicated imo. Maybe if you don't know what OP is trying to do don't write an answer?

Comment: @frostzt If you don't know what the OP is trying to do, ask for clarification in comments. And no, I did understand your idea, I just say that "gaining a separate stack" is not better but actually wrong giving the looping condition.